# How to make input into powershell colored?

Tags: powershell

I've programmed in the past and I remember having a terminal that would change the colors of words depending on their function (different color for variables, different color if I imported something etc). How is this accomplished in general? I installed Pygments but it seems that just does it for text files.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You're probably looking for [`PSReadLine`](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine).

Answer (score 1):

Powershell ISE with Powershell Version 4.0+ Includes some good coloring features for interactive scripting.

[image: screenshot]

Powershell v2 ships with Windows 7, v4 can be downloaded and ISE is on the machine already. Current powershell version is v5, but beware-- some software like Server 2008 R2 running Exchange 2010 is built on v2, and a lot of the cmdlets won't work for v3-v5 without PS-Sessions.

In case you were curious about coloring *output* to the host, you can just do

```
Write-Host "my string" -fore 'color' -back 'color'
```

If you want a fully-fledged powershell IDE, you can purchase SAPIEN Powershell Studio which also wraps scripts in Windows Forms, can build MSI packages and similar things. If you're a hard core powershell kind of guy, it may be worth your time if making GUI powershell applications.

Comment: Powershell 5 has syntax highlighting for the regular shell (and of course ISE) out of the box.

Comment: @bluuf That's because it ships with [`PSReadLine`](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine).